# Convergence in distribution with constant expectation

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose that $X_n$ converges to $X$ in distribution and $\mathbb{E}[X_n] = 1$ for all $n.$ Is it true that $\mathbb{E}[X]= 1?$

My answer is no. I think if we take $X_n = n I (0 ,1/n)$, then $\mathbb{E}[X_n] = 1$, but $E[X] = 0.$ However, this is only true of $X_n$ converges to $0$ in distribution, which I am not sure about.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: As your example suggests,  $X_{n}\xrightarrow{d} X$ does not imply  $E[X_{n}]\to E[X]$ . But WHAT do you claim ,is true if $X_{n}\xrightarrow{d} 0$ in distribution ? You should elaborate more on what exactly your question is

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron If $X_n$ converges to $0$ in distribution then I am claiming that $\mathbb{E}[X] = 0.$

Comment: That is just trivially true. If $X$ , the limiting rv has distribution $0$ then expectation is obviously $0$. Do you want to ask  if $X_{n}\xrightarrow{d} 0$ implies $E[X_{n}]\to 0$ ?

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron If that is true then would my counterexample disprove the statement?

Comment: Yes it would ovbiously .